# Is customizing YAML Serialization in python using decorator implemented somewhere?

Tags: python, serialization, deserialization, yaml

I'm writing a YAML configuration serialization in python (using YAML because its a tree of objects configuration and I want the configuration to be as humanly readable as possible).

I have several problems with this:

1. Several internal (non configuration) members that are used by the objects  and thus I wish not to store in the config file
2. Some configuration members have default values, I don't want to store them if they are default (this also does not touch deserialization)

In Java you had [jackson annotations](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations) s.a. `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` and others that do this for json files, I found nothing similar for yaml (or even for JSON) in python, I know how to write this (using YAML package API) but I'd rather not if it's already implemented somewhere.

example of a class I would like to serialize

```
 class Locator(object):
     def __init__(self, multiple=False):
         # configurable parameters
         self.multiple = multiple

         # internal parameters (used in locate method)
         self.precedents = []
         self.segments
         self.probabilities = []
        def locate(self, message):
         """
          do stuff to locate stuff on message
         """ . . .
             yield segment
```

Here we see the root class that holds configuration parameter (multiple) which I only wish to serialize if it is True and other members that are used in its operation s.a. sons (precedents) etc... which I don't want to serialize at all

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Can you include an example of python -->  YAML? I think I understand your question but I don't know enough Java to understand the equivalent.

Comment: I'm writing this in python, Java has a solution I linked to under Jackson annotations (p.s. I never actually used them but)... they seem to handle everything I need which is: set the fields I want to serialize and don't serialize default constructor values.

Comment: Example of what? of the class I want to serialize?

Comment: I guess that's what I'm asking but I'm not sure if that's enough to answer the question. I'm also not sure from your comment of the usefulness of not serializing constructor defaults. I'm not the downloader btw.

Comment: Whatever you're about to post, it won't make sense. Formatting in comments is crap and illegible. Edit it in to the question please.

Comment: That's ok. I take no offense for the down grade as I actually need this one answered for work purposes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the honest answer is "probably not", and the reason is that what you're reaching for here just isn't really idiomatic in Python. If you squint a little, there is a strong resemblance between Python dicts and JSON objects -- and squint some more and YAML looks like a whitespace-y dialect of JSON -- so when we need to serialize `thing`s from Python we tend to write some custom mapping of `thing` to dict, stuff it in a JSON/YAML serializer, and be done with it.

There are some shortcuts and idiomatic trickery that can come in handy in the `thing => dict` step. For example, a namedtuple subclass with methods on it will leave said methods out when you call `asdict` on it:

```
In [1]: from collections import namedtuple

In [2]: class Locator(namedtuple("Locator", "foo bar baz")):
   ...:     def hide(self):
   ...:         pass
   ...:

In [3]: wow = Locator(1,2,3)

In [4]: wow._asdict()
Out[4]: OrderedDict([('foo', 1), ('bar', 2), ('baz', 3)])
```

Of course a tuple is not mutable, so this is not a general purpose solution if you really need a class with mutable attributes, and furthermore this doesn't address your desire to drop certain attributes from the serialization in a declarative way.

One nice third party library that might fit your needs is [attrs](http://www.attrs.org/)... this library provides something like an extra-fancy namedtuple with a lot of customizability, including filters and defaults, which you might be able to work in to something you find comfortable. It's not 1:1 with what you're reaching for here but it could be a start.

Comment: The attrs suggestion is relevant but I don't find this an extremely un pythonic request, why not have decorators that implement customary hiding of certain members in serialization?

Anyway, you're the only runner up for this bounty so far.

Comment: It's certainly possible, my thought is mostly a sort of hypothesis at a historical narrative: that in Java, mapping a serialization from a POJO with some library is standard fare because of the impedance mismatch with the serialization target; in Python, a better match there in terms of the form of the native dict type, more or less by accident, has caused this to be less of an itch, thus nobody (to my knowledge) has scratched it quite so thoroughly.

Comment: If no one answers (which seems likely at this point) the bounty is yours tomorrow, I also went through some of your questions/ answers and upvoted some.

Comment: BTW, is there any way in attr to filter default values other than attr.asdict(a, filter=lambda x, v: x.default != v ) ?

Comment: `attr.filters` has a couple helpers, but you probably saw that already

Comment: Yep i ended up not using attr cause it doesn't play well with class hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution I wrote meanwhile for JSON, but's its very specific and I would love to find a package that already solved this is a more general manner

```
class LocatorEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    """
        custom Locator json encoder to encode only configuration related parameters
        it encodes only :
            1. protected data members (whose names start with a single '_'
            2. members that are different from their default value

        NOTE: for this filtering encoder to work two strong conventions must be upheld, namely:
            1. Configuration data members must start with a single preceding '_'
            2. They must differ from their correlated __init__ parameter by only that '_'
    """
    @staticmethod
    def get_default_args(f):
        return {
            k: v.default
            for k, v in inspect.signature(f).parameters.items()
            if v.default is not inspect.Parameter.empty
        }

    @staticmethod
    def filter(d, defaults):
        """
            this is the filtering method
        :param d: dictionary of members to filter
        :param defaults: default values to filter out
        :return: ordered dictionary with only protected members ('_') that do not have their default value
            the return dictionary is ordered because it prints nicer
        """
        filtered = OrderedDict()
        for k, v in d.items():
            # this is the filter logic (key starts with one _ and is not its default value)
            if (re.match(r'_[^_]', k)) and (k[1:] not in defaults or defaults[k[1:]] != v):
                filtered[k] = v
        return filtered

    def default(self, o):
        """
            iterate on classes in the objects mro and build a list of default constructor values

        :param o: the object to be json encoded
        :return: encoded dictionary for the object serialization
        """
        if isinstance(o, Locator):
            defaults = {}
            for cl in o.__class__.mro():
                # iterate on all the default arguments of the __init__ method
                for k, v in self.get_default_args(cl.__init__).items():
                    # update the key with value if it doesn't already exist
                    defaults[k] = defaults.get(k, v)

            # build the filtered configuration data members and add precedent in a recursive call to this default method
            filtered_dictionary = self.filter(o.__dict__, defaults)
            precedents = []
            for precedent in o.precedents:
                precedents.append(self.default(precedent))
            filtered_dictionary["precedents"] = precedents

            return {'__{}__'.format(o.__class__.__name__): filtered_dictionary}
        return super().default(self, o)
```